# Mongoid: Change(rename) foreign_key name without loosing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I would like to change the foreign key of relation. Lets say I have a class:

```
class Car
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :model, type: String

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :random_key_id 
end
```

and I have database with few Car instances. I want to change foreign key of user on car

```
class Car
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :model, type: String

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :owner_id
end
```

but when I just change definition like above than all cars in database loose their connection to `.user`. In SQL database I would just generate migration with rename column. How to solve in mongoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interface directly with MongoDB to [rename the field](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/).

So fire up your Mongo shell and run this:

```
db.cars.update({}, {$rename:{"random_key_id":"owner_id"}}, false, true);
```

If you are not familiar with using the Mongo shell then [start here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/).